# How to make a inner join with condition...?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

SQL Server 2000

Using More than 20 views, all the views are inner join with table1 (id and value1 and value2)

Table1

```
ID Value1 Value2

001 100 null
001 200 null
001 300 null
001 400 null
001 200 null
```

or

```
ID Value1 Value2

001 null 100 
001 null 200 
001 null 300 
001 null 400 
001 null 200
```

Table2

```
ID value1 value2

....
....

some data's
```

from the table1, either value1 or value2 should always be null. now the problem is if the
value1 or value2 column is null, then output is showing null because all the views are inner join with id, value1, value2

I want to make a inner join with condition, if the value1 is not null then inner join with
value1 or if the value2 is not null then inner join with value2

Query like this

```
Select * from table2 inner join with table1 on tabel2.id = table1.id and if table1.value1 is null then table2.value2 = table1.value2 or
else table2.value1 = table1= value1 end if
```

How to make a query for the above condition

Need SQL Query Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like the following work?

```
SELECT * FROM table2
INNER JOIN WITH table1 ON table2.id = table1.id
    AND (table1.value1 = table2.value1 OR table1.value1 IS NULL)
    AND (table1.value2 = table2.value2 OR table1.value2 IS NULL)
```

I think this might prove to be quite slow if you had a large data set however...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `coalesce(value1, value2)`?

Comment: select * from Table2 inner join (select coalesce(Value1, Value2) from Table1) t1 on Table2.ID = t1.ID

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of: `select * from table2 t2 inner join t1 on t1.id = t2.id and coalesce(t1.value1, t1.value2) = coalesce(t2.value1, t2.value2)`

Comment: I agree, however in terms of results, I think its even faster if we do this: select coalesce(t1.value1, t1.value2) from table1 t1 union select coalesce(t2.value1, t2.value2) from table2 t2

Comment: edit your question to show what you are trying, and the results you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
Select * 
from table2 
inner join table1 on (tabel2.id = table1.id 
                      and table1.value1 is null 
                      and table2.value2 = table1.value2) 
                  or ( table2.value1 = table1.value1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table2 t2
INNER JOIN WITH table1 t1 ON table2.id = table1.id
On (CASE WHEN t1.value1 is null then t1.value2=t2.value2 else t1.value1=t2.value1)
and
(CASE WHEN t2.value1 is null then t2.value2=t1.value2 else t2.value1=t1.value1)
```